# Can poulet noir be prepared as standard chicken, or is there anything special to consider?

Tags: chicken, oven

I got "poulet noir" or "black feathered chicken" for Christmas, but I couldn't find much information about it or how to prepare it.

Is it safe to assume, that it can be prepared like any other chicken, or are there considerations to take into account for this particular race of chicken?

The only information I found about this chicken is, that it is low in fat, lives semi-wild, whatever that means and is maybe gamier than normal chicken.

Should I just follow standard chicken recipes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how much <s>fitness it did</s> space it had to run around in, this type of chicken is best used in a stew, so depending on your personal chicken recipes, yes, use the standard ones but ***do not***:

- BBQ
- Fry
- Roast
- Bake it in an open container (A closed closed container with moisture-releasing veggies is still OK)

#### ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: hmmm... I planned to actually roast it, as a goose replacement. Wouldn't it perform similarly to a duck or a goose in that regard? What is the downside? If roasting, definitely close? Maybe even butter it inside the skin, like a turkey? Stuff with onions and a lemon for added moisture?

Comment: Well... If you were planning on doing that, you should have asked that instead! **;-)**  But no: it's not as fat as a goose or duck, so you'd have to smear some duck or goose fat all over and in it and then encase it in aluminium foil which is the same as using a closed container.  If you would have a [Römertopf](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/R%C3%B6mertopf) handy that would be ideal...

Comment: Actually, I did buy a römertopf for this occasion. Thanks for the tips!